# Convert Excel or Numbers (mac) hyperlink to html a tags

Tags: html, excel, ms-word, href, apple-numbers

I'm trying to convert an Excel, Word, or Numbers hyperlink to HTML `<a>` tag.

For example, I have [linkName] and need 
`<a href='URL'>[linkName]</a>`.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: do you use same url or different url in each case? is the linkname same as url in each case?

Comment: Different URL in each case, and in some cases I use two links per cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a hard research I've found an answer that works, in word or excel you can create a new macro and run it later.

To create a macro, go to 'view->macros' create a new one and paste this code:

```
Sub AddHREF()
' Turn Word hyperlinks into <a href...> HTML tags
Dim i As Integer
For i = ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Count To 1 Step -1
  With ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks(i)
   If InStr(1, .Address, "http://www.gaebler.com", 1) Then
      .Range = "<a href=""" & Replace(.Address, "http://www.gaebler.com", "") & """>" _
      & Replace(Replace(.TextToDisplay, "<strong>", ""), "</strong>", "") & "</a>"
   Else
      .Range = "<a href=""" & .Address & """ target=""_blank"" rel=""nofollow"">" & _
      Replace(Replace(.TextToDisplay, "<strong>", ""), "</strong>", "") & "</a>"
   End If
  End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Then just run the macro and the magic appears!